# Syntax problems in Matrix addition and multipication program

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

i am trying to compile this program where i entered two 3*3 arrays and i am multipyling and adding both of them. However it is giving me some errors at the end due to which its not running. I cant remove these errors and i need help regarding how can i remove them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Matrix{
public static void main(String [] args){
int a [][]= new int [3][3];
int b [][]= new int [3][3];
int C [][]= new int [3][3];
int d [][]= new int [3][3];
Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter Numbers in first matrix");
for( int r=0; r<3; r++){
    for( int c=0; c<3; c++){
a [r][c]= in.nextInt();
}
}

System.out.println("Matrix 1 : ");
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  System.out.print(" "+ a[i][j]);
  }
  System.out.println();
  }  

System.out.println("Enter Numbers in 2nd matrix");
for( int n=0; n<3; n++){
    for( int m=0; m<3; m++){

b [n][m]= in.nextInt();
}
}

System.out.println("Matrix 2 : ");
  for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
  for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
  System.out.print(" "+b[k][l]);
  }  
  System.out.println();
  }

  //for multiplication of the matrices
  for(int f = 0; f < 3; f++) {
  for(int s = 0; s < 3; s++) {
  for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++){

  C[f][s] += a[f][d]*b[d][s];
  }
  }  
 }
  System.out.println("Multiplication of both matrix : ");
  for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
  System.out.print(" "+C[x][y]);
  }  
  System.out.println();
  }
  }

// for addition of both matrices

for(int w=0; w < 3; w++) {
  for(int u=0; u < 3; u++) {
d[w][u] = a[w][u]+b[w][u];
}
}

System.out.println("Addition of both matrix : ");
  for(int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
  for(int q = 0; q < 3; q++) {
  System.out.print(" "+ d[p][q]);
  }  
  System.out.println();
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well what are the errors?

Comment: "...due to some errors" what errors? How other people with same problem would find your question and potential solutions if you will not include any informations about problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: BTW, you need to check number of your braces `{` `}`. Hint: start using indentation properly, of if you don't know how let your IDE handle it for you (in Eclipse you just can press `Ctrl`+`I`).

Answer (score 1):

Use an IDE and indent your program. You would see the issues. You have two issues issues:

1. You have an extra parenthesis. I would not tell you where.
2. You have "d" defined twice as a variable.

Again, it it time to download and use an IDE and indent code.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd ident your code properly, you'll see that you have an extra "}":

```
  System.out.println("Multiplication of both matrix : ");
  for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
      System.out.print(" "+C[x][y]);
    }  
    System.out.println();
  }
  }  // Remove this
```

You also have the variable `d` declared twice:

```
int d [][]= new int [3][3];
...
for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++){
```